# Cannot get auto optimizer stats collection job to run after Oracle 11g upgrade

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, scheduler

We recently upgraded our 10g server to 11g (11.2.0.3.0), and I see that stats gathering should be handled via the Automated Maintenance Tasks feature - specifically the "auto optimizer stats collection" job.

However, since our upgrade (5 days ago), I have not seen any of these jobs run in the scheduler, and the Automated Maintenance Tasks interface in OEM does not show the jobs having been run.  DBA_AUTOTASK_JOB_HISTORY has no rows, and I see no history of any stat job running in the scheduler tab or OEM, yet as far as I can tell, the system is configured correctly:

```
    SELECT col
         , val
      FROM ( SELECT *
               FROM DBA_AUTOTASK_CLIENT
              WHERE CLIENT_NAME = 'auto optimizer stats collection'
           )
   UNPIVOT (    val                            
            FOR col                              
             IN ( CLIENT_NAME
                , STATUS
                , CONSUMER_GROUP
                , CLIENT_TAG
                , PRIORITY_OVERRIDE
                , ATTRIBUTES
                , WINDOW_GROUP
                , SERVICE_NAME
                )
           );

  COL               VAL
  ----------------- ---------------------------------------
  CLIENT_NAME       auto optimizer stats collection
  STATUS            ENABLED
  CONSUMER_GROUP    ORA$AUTOTASK_STATS_GROUP
  CLIENT_TAG        OS
  PRIORITY_OVERRIDE INVALID
  ATTRIBUTES        ON BY DEFAULT, VOLATILE, SAFE TO KILL
  WINDOW_GROUP      ORA$AT_WGRP_OS


  SQL> select * from DBA_AUTOTASK_WINDOW_CLIENTS;

  WINDOW_NAME                    WINDOW_NEXT_TIME                                                            WINDO AUTOTASK OPTIMIZE SEGMENT_ SQL_TUNE HEALTH_M
  ------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
  MONDAY_WINDOW                  01-NOV-12 10.00.00.000000 AM AMERICA/NEW_YORK                               FALSE ENABLED  ENABLED  DISABLED ENABLED  DISABLED
  TUESDAY_WINDOW                 01-NOV-12 10.00.00.000000 AM AMERICA/NEW_YORK                               FALSE ENABLED  ENABLED  DISABLED ENABLED  DISABLED
  WEDNESDAY_WINDOW               01-NOV-12 10.00.00.000000 AM AMERICA/NEW_YORK                               FALSE ENABLED  ENABLED  DISABLED ENABLED  DISABLED
  THURSDAY_WINDOW                01-NOV-12 10.00.00.000000 AM AMERICA/NEW_YORK                               FALSE ENABLED  ENABLED  DISABLED ENABLED  DISABLED
  FRIDAY_WINDOW                  01-NOV-12 10.00.00.000000 AM AMERICA/NEW_YORK                               FALSE ENABLED  ENABLED  DISABLED ENABLED  DISABLED
  SATURDAY_WINDOW                01-NOV-12 10.00.00.000000 AM AMERICA/NEW_YORK                               FALSE ENABLED  ENABLED  DISABLED ENABLED  DISABLED
  SUNDAY_WINDOW                  01-NOV-12 10.00.00.000000 AM AMERICA/NEW_YORK                               FALSE ENABLED  ENABLED  DISABLED ENABLED  DISABLED
```

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Cause

Just want to share the solution for all who will face this problem in the future.

This problem is caused when you shutdown the database for maintenance etc while one of the scheduler window is active and corresponding auto maintenance job is running. So when the database is shutdown, corresponding job is killed by the status of maintenance window remains active.

This can be confirmed by following query.

```
SQL> select window_name,active from DBA_SCHEDULER_WINDOWS;

WINDOW_NAME                    ACTIV
------------------------------ -----
WEEKNIGHT_WINDOW               FALSE
WEEKEND_WINDOW                 FALSE
MONDAY_WINDOW                  FALSE
TUESDAY_WINDOW                 FALSE
WEDNESDAY_WINDOW               FALSE
THURSDAY_WINDOW                FALSE
FRIDAY_WINDOW                  FALSE
SATURDAY_WINDOW                TRUE         <-- This is still active.
SUNDAY_WINDOW                  FALSE
```

Following query is showing that currently there are no auto stats job is running.

```
SQL> select CLIENT_NAME,JOB_NAME,JOB_SCHEDULER_STATUS
  2  from DBA_AUTOTASK_CLIENT_JOB
  3  where client_name = 'auto optimizer stats collection';
```

no rows selected

## Solution

close the active window.

```
SQL> EXECUTE DBMS_SCHEDULER.CLOSE_WINDOW ('SATURDAY_WINDOW');
```

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

```
SQL> select window_name,active from DBA_SCHEDULER_WINDOWS;

WINDOW_NAME                    ACTIV
------------------------------ -----
WEEKNIGHT_WINDOW               FALSE
WEEKEND_WINDOW                 FALSE
MONDAY_WINDOW                  FALSE
TUESDAY_WINDOW                 FALSE
WEDNESDAY_WINDOW               FALSE
THURSDAY_WINDOW                FALSE
FRIDAY_WINDOW                  FALSE
SATURDAY_WINDOW                FALSE
SUNDAY_WINDOW                  FALSE
```

Next time your job will run just fine.

Answer (score 1):

See the following My Oracle Support (MOS) Article:  Scheduled Maintenance Auto Tasks Not Working After 11.2.0.3 Upgrade [ID 1452836.1]

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be helpful if you can provide the link.

Comment: That's the same kind of answer you gave [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10799997#jive-message-10799997); also, without a link.